# How to select value in row over sheet by copy without jump row Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel like this

[image]

and i need to copy value to another sheet by this pattern

[image: https://ibb.co/2WH0ZLQ]

i just try to copy but value incorrect because there pair by row cell over sheet

How can i copy and get value in each row value thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the formula below on the first cell of any column of the same sheet and copy it all the column down:

```
=+IF(MOD(ROW(A1),4)=1,"NAME",IF(MOD(ROW(A1),4)=3,CONCATENATE("value ",INDEX(B:B,QUOTIENT(ROW(A1),4)+2)),""))
```

See screenshot of the result.

[image]

Comment: It's work!!! thank you guy. this is what i need IF(MOD(ROW(A1),4)=3,CONCATENATE("value ",INDEX(B:B,QUOTIENT(ROW(A1),4)+2)),"")